# cannot configure example-events for react-leaflet v3 to play

Tags: react-leaflet

I am trying to set up a react app for the following example https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/example-events but cannot make it work due to compile errors. The same example in v2 works for me.

```
import React, {Component,useState} from 'react'
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker,useMapEvents } from 'react-leaflet'
import Popup from 'react-leaflet-editable-popup'


function LocationMarker() {
    const [position, setPosition] = useState(null)
    const map = useMapEvents({
        click() {
            map.locate()
        },
        locationfound(e) {
            setPosition(e.latlng)
            map.flyTo(e.latlng, map.getZoom())
        },
    })

    return position === null ? null : (
        <Marker position={position} removable editable>
            <Popup>You are here</Popup>
        </Marker>
    )
}
class Map extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <MapContainer
                center={{ lat: 51.505, lng: -0.09 }}
                zoom={13}
                scrollWheelZoom={false}
                id="mapId">
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                <LocationMarker />
            </MapContainer>
        )
    }

}


export default Map;
```

If i don't use a class i get render underfined error. If i try to use the function does not work.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue and it's related with
`import Popup from 'react-leaflet-editable-popup'`
This package is not compatible with react-leaflet v3
This minor edit was crashing my example.
without this edit it works

Comment: react-leaflet-editable-popup is support to react-leaflet v3

https://github.com/slutske22/react-leaflet-editable-popup/releases/tag/2.0.4

Answer (score 1):

### try it

```
import React, {Component,useState} from 'react'
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker,useMapEvents } from 'react-leaflet'
import Popup from 'react-leaflet-editable-popup'


function LocationMarker(props) {
    const [position, setPosition] = useState(null)
    const map = useMapEvents({
        click() {
            map.locate()
        },
        moveend() {
            let center = map.getCenter();
            let zoom = map.getZoom();

            props.effectOn.setState(state => {
                state.lat = center.lat;
                state.lng = center.lng;
                return { ...state }
            });
        },
        locationfound(e) {
            setPosition(e.latlng)
            map.flyTo(e.latlng, map.getZoom())
        },
    })

    return position === null ? null : (
        <Marker position={position} removable editable>
            <Popup>You are here</Popup>
        </Marker>
    )
}
class Map extends Component{
    state = {
        lat: 35.76218444303944,
        lng: 51.33657932281495
    };

    render(){
        return(
            <MapContainer
                center={[this.state.lat, this.state.lng]}
                zoom={13}
                scrollWheelZoom={false}
                id="mapId">
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />
                <LocationMarker effectOn={this}/>
            </MapContainer>
        )
    }

}


export default Map;
```

Comment: I tried the above but still doesn't work for me.
Works fine if i just remove the editable popup and place a normal one.