# Why it is giving me a Hook warning, while I am not using any hooks in my component?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-hooks

I am trying to display Leaflet Map as a React component. Once I try to use this component I get the error:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

My component is taken from [Leaflet-React-Example](https://react-leaflet.js.org/), in the end my component looks as:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";

const position = [51.405, -0.09];

export default class LeafLetSubmitMap extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MapContainer center={position} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker position={position}>
          <Popup>
            Is it changing? <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

Then once I use the element in a class importing as `import LeafLetSubmitMap from "./lefletMap";` I get the above error. There might be versioning issue, but I tried several permutations. Currently I have these installed:

```
+-- leaflet@1.7.1
+-- react@17.0.1
+-- react-dom@17.0.1
`-- react-leaflet@3.0.2
```

Full list of dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "antd": "^4.8.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "joi-browser": "^13.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "mapbox-gl": "^1.12.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-aws-s3": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-owl-carousel": "^2.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "react-toastify": "^6.0.9",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
```

This looks to be easy to be added, though I am failing to do so. Is there something which I need to know in order how to add it? As my main goal is to be able to find address locations and store the langtitude and latitude, as well the address in MongoDB.

Tried the functional component as suggested, still the same error.

```
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from "react-leaflet";
const position = [51.405, -0.09];

export default function LeafLetSubmitMap() {
  return (
    <MapContainer center={position} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <Marker position={position}>
        <Popup>
          Is it changing? <br /> Easily customizable.
        </Popup>
      </Marker>
    </MapContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: ```const position = [51.405, -0.09];``` should be inside render ()

Comment: try to remove Popup component from render, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64785660/5706630

Comment: @jarivak why would it need to be inside? I tried this, but it didn't work. The const defined in the file can be used anywhere. I don't see a specific reason to be inside.

@Roy.B here it `import Popup from 'react-leaflet-editable-popup'` was used, which I am not using, Though tried to remove this part as your suggestion, it didn't work. 

Additionally have tried to leave only `MapContainer` with `TileLayer`. The same error

Comment: @YoungDad the problem is one of the components in render using useEffect and you cannot useEfect in react class component so maybe change LeafLetSubmitMap to be function component sense you don't use any react life cycle in it anyway and it should work

Comment: @Roy.B this was a good guess, while I was excited that this could be it, it didn't work, Added the code in the edited version. :(.

Comment: @YoungDad I've created a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-shamir-mivhs?file=/src/App.js:98-111, the code is working fine, maybe the error comes from the upper level, e.g  from where LeafLetSubmitMap is been called

Comment: @Roy.B, if I am removing this code it is working fine. So it could be interference somehow? Ahh, that sounds painful to find it out. Though so much appreciated the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add 'react-leaflet' and 'leaflet' to your list of dependencies. Run `npm add leaflet` and `npm add react-leaflet`- there is some kind of version clash here whereby the `useEffect` hook in the MapContainer class is unable to be called in a function. Also make sure that you have imported the leaflet css otherwise the map won't render. Either by creating a div with styling to wrap your MapContainer or by editing the leaflet-container in the leaflet.css:

```css
.leaflet-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 400px;
    }
```